# Skipping Items During Data Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, databound-controls

Greetings!

I have a Repeater control that's using an XmlDataSource control.

```
<asp:FormView id="myFormView" runat="server" DataSourceID="myXmlDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <span>Items</span>
        <asp:Repeater id="myRepeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("Items/*")%>'>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><%# XPath("text()")%></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>            
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <span>Things</span>
        <asp:Repeater id="myRepeater2" runat="server" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("Things/*")%>'>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><%# XPath("text()")%></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>            
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>        
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="myXmlDataSource" XPath="Root" EnableCaching="false" runat="server" />
```

The XML looks something like this:

```
<Root>
    <Items>
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>
        <Item>D</Item>
    </Items>
    <Things>
        <Thing>1</Thing>
        <Thing>2</Thing>
        <Thing>3</Thing>
    </Things>
</Root>
```

In some cases, I'd like to "skip" the "B" item when binding so that it isn't displayed.  Is there a way during the DataBinding event that I could skip the binding of the "B" item so that it won't be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could investigate the current DataItem in the OnItemDataBound() method of the repeater and skip processing that item if it matches your criteria

Comment: I was thinking that might the best answer, would you just override the OnItemDataBound and choose to omit calling it's base method when you find an item you wish to omit?

Comment: How is "skip processing" accomplished?

Comment: I think I answered my own question: by setting the DataItem's visibility to false.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend changing your XPath from "Root" to something that will only include items you want to bind, if you are using an XmlDataSource.